# бот должен выдавать id

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", parse_mode="HTML")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  user_id = message.from_user.id

bot.polling()
```

Написал бота, который должен выводить id человека ему в лс! Бот не работает, почему?

Comment: помогите пожалуйста) Вопрос жизни и смерти

Answer (score 0):

Так ты даже ничего не отсылаешь юзеру. Ты просто в переменную записал его ID

Напиши так:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
  user_id = message.from_user.id
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, user_id) 

bot.polling()
```

Comment: огромное спасибо)))

Comment: а ты не знаешь ли как сделать так, чтобы бот выдавал айпи человека?

Comment: @ВячеславГвоздиков это вообще почти невозможно. Знаю, как свой вычислить...

Comment: а ты не знаешь ли случайно, как получить доступ к роутеру соседа?

Comment: @ВячеславГвоздиков да вы имеете хакерские наклонности, уважаемый. И даже не стесняетесь задавать такие вопросы